# Cannot import most libraries out there due to their compiler version being too old

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.8.x

My Contract has `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;` but I am using [this library](https://github.com/willitscale/solidity-util) to be able to split strings that uses `pragma solidity ^0.5.0;`.

Changing this line alone wont fix the issue, it will create new ones (other compilation errors).

What can I do?

```
[1] Compiling your contracts...
[1] ===========================
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\access\Ownable.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\IERC721.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\IERC721Receiver.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\extensions\IERC721Metadata.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Address.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Context.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Strings.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\introspection\ERC165.sol
[1] > Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\introspection\IERC165.sol
[1] > Compiling .\contracts\MyContract.sol
[1] > Compiling solidity-util\lib\Strings.sol
[1] 
[1] ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered 
to be strictly less than the released version
[1]  --> solidity-util/lib/Strings.sol:1:1:
[1]   |
[1] 1 | pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
[1]   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[1]
[1]
[1] Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.8.7, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.5.0".
[1] Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).
[1] (See https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
[1] configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using pragma solidity <= 0.8.0 in your current contract that you referred here as My Contract

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't had any effect. I added the error logs in the OP.

Comment: also configure your truffle compiler version accordingly as well

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to avoid that, because I want to use the new safeMath features only available on 0.8.0+. It is sad that they have breaking changes between minor versioning. In the end, I just noticed that 0.8.0 already accepts string[] as function arguments so I don't need to use the old library I was trying to use anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you use truffle compiler, you can try the following steps

1. specify openzeppelin version in `package.json`,

   "dependencies": {
   "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.4.0"
   },
2. run `npm install` to install specified version dependence.
3. run `truffle compile`